# Watchdog too fast for apache PID-file

Tags: watchdog

I am running Ubuntu Trusty on an ARM embedded board. Init System is Upstart. The watchdog (v5.13) should supervise the apache server. Obviously the watchdog is testing for the apache pid-file before it is generated. This leads to a reboot loop. What would be an appropriate approch to solve this issue?

- Adding delay via watchdog repair-binary / repair-timeout? (As far as this is possible)
- Adding delay / change start sequence via the init process?

Thanks in advance.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

The latest watchdog code supports a time-out and retry behaviour for exactly this sort of thing! Get the code from https://sourceforge.net/p/watchdog/code/ci/master/tree/ and build it and see if that helps. More info on building process can be found here, even though it is referring to an experimental version: http://www.sat.dundee.ac.uk/~psc/watchdog/watchdog-version-6.html